# For a given matrix, how to find the vector which results in the greatest scaling?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $A$ and the norm $||A||=max\{||Ax||:||x||=1\}$. 
I know the norm is equal to the largest singular value of $A$. How do I find the $x$ that maximises the norm? Is it the corresponding eigenvector of of $AA^{*}$?

Comment: A vector in the domain of the $A$

Comment: Say $A$ is $m \times n$, $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Comment: And $$\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\overline{x}_i}.$$

Comment: $x^*$ is the maximizer of $\|Ax\|$ s.t. $\|x\|=1$ if and only if $x^*$ is an unit eigenvector to largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$. (Which may be not an eigenvector of $AA^*$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\|Ax\|^2 = (Ax)^*Ax = x^*(A^*A)x
$$
and by the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, we have
$$
\lambda_{max}(A^*A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} x^*(A^*A)x
$$
So, it will in fact be the corresponding eigenvector of $A^*A$ (as opposed to that of $AA^*$).